# axios - why can't I override the request header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     accept: 'application/json',
  },
  baseURL: 'https://my-site.com',
};
const axiosInstance = axios.create({config});

// override here 
const result = await axiosInstance.get('url', {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken, Accept: '*/*' },
        params: {}
})
```

In the request header, `Accept` still shows the 'application/json' instead of `*/*`, while the `Authorization` shows correct value.

How to override the header in `axiosInstance.get`?

**Update**
My problem is similar to https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1819

Comment: The last comment in that issue thread mentions `accept` vs `Accept`. Try standardizing your header maybe? I believe you should only be using `Accept`, not `accept` as on line 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you set the accept header instead of the Accept header. In the first case, the value is appended to the default. In the second case, the value is replaced.

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-einstein-0ye2gq